# Laplace-Beltrami of the Gauss map

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, harmonic-functions

I'm looking for the proof of very nice identity about the Laplace-Beltrami operator of the Gauss map $N$ of a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by a patch $X$. I want to show that

$$\Delta N = -2g^{ij} \partial_i H \partial_j X - 2(2H^2-K)N,$$

where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $M$ (applied componentwise on the Gauss map $N$). Unfortunately I did not find a proof for this in any book on differential geometry.
It would be awesome if somebody could give a hint or a reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are calculating at a normal coordinate $(x_1, x_2)$ at $x$. Then

$$\begin{split}\nabla_i N &= \langle \nabla_i N, e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle \nabla_i N, e_1\rangle e_1 \\
&= -h_{1i} e_1 -h_{2i} e_2
\end{split}$$

Differentiate again,

$$\nabla_i \nabla _i N = -(\nabla_i h_{1i}) e_1 - (\nabla_i h_{2i}) e_2 -  (h_{1i})^2N - (h_{2i})^2 N . $$

Using the Codazzi equation, $\nabla_i h_{jk} = \nabla_jh_{ik}$, we have \

$$\nabla_i \nabla _i N = -( \nabla_1 h_{ii} e_1 - \nabla_2 h_{ii}) e_2 -( h_{1i}^2 + h_{2i}^2) N . $$

If we sum over $i  =1, 2$, using $H = \frac 12 (h_{11} + h_{22})$ and $K = h_{11} h_{22} - h_{12}^2$, we have

$$\Delta N = \sum \nabla_ i \nabla_i N = -2\nabla_i H e_i -2(2H^2 -K) N,$$

which is what you want.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct, if we assume that the coordinates are normal. I know that we can always assume Riemmanian normal coordinates using the exponential map. However, why can we conclude that the equation holds valid for any choice of coordinates?

Comment: @fr78: As the equation can be written in such a way that it is independent of coordinate: $\Delta N = -2 \nabla H - 2(2H^2 -K)N$. Then to prove this it suffices to use any coordinate system.

Comment: why is $<\nabla_{e_i}N,e_1>=-h_{1i}$ true? The connection here is connection on $M$ not the usual connection $D$ on $\mathcal{R}^n.$

Comment: @H-H The connection here is indeed the usual connection on $\mathbb R^3$. Note that $N$ is $\mathbb R^3$-valued, so there is no "connection on $M$" that can be applied on $N$.

Comment: @John Ma When I look at the definition of rough Laplacian of vector field $X$ on hypersurface $M$, it is defined to be $\Delta X=-\sum_{i=1}^n (\nabla_{e_i}\nabla_{e_i}X-\nabla_{\nabla_{e_i}e_i}X)$ where $\nabla$ is the connection on $M$, did i misunderstand anything here?

Comment: @H-H whenever you have a vector bundle $E\to M$ with a connection $D$, one can define the rough Laplacian as $\Delta_D X = -\sum (D_{e_i} D_{e_i} X - D_{\nabla_{e_i} e_i} X)$ where $X$ is a smooth section of $E$. Now $N$ is a section on the trivial bunde $E = M \times \mathbb R^3$ and it has the trivial connection (just taking partial derivative on each coordinates)